# Are there any frameworks for remote scripting of both windows and unix?

Tags: ruby, windows, unix

I'm trying to automate the refresh procedures of our development environments, and was wondering if there were any scripting frameworks (or programs) out there for running scripts against both windows and unix servers. For example:

1. Connect to unix webserver, run shutdown script
2. Connect to unix appserver, run shutdown script
3. Connect to windows report server, run shutdown script
4. Connect to unix database server, run database shutdown script, run sql script, startup database

I've been playing around with writing ruby scripts to accomplish this, but was wondering what some alternatives might be.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to level the playing field by running an SSH server on your Windows machine.

Look here for some suggestions -> https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows